# Why is Text content stretching?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My view has a dynamic `Text`element which updates its contents based on the current winning streak of a player.

```
if player1Streak > 0 || player2Streak > 0 {
    HStack {
        Text("Winning streak:")
        Text(player1Streak > 0 ? "\(player1Streak)" : "\(player2Streak)")
        Text(player1Streak > 0 ? "(\(player1Name))" : "(\(player2Name))")
    }
}
```

Here's how it's supposed to look:

[image: correct size]

Problem is that the `Text` seems to stretch randomly. Sometimes it's wide and the text truncates:

[image: wide]

Other times it shrinks like this:

[image: shrinked]

I am running the app in the Simulator. Is there something wrong with my code or is this a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug in iOS 13 beta. I've noticed this behavior in Slack and it was definitely not intentional.

Comment: Yep, I'm seeing the same behavior. It even happens if you move the conditional outside the `Text` initializer argument, as: `condition? Text("condition 1") : Text("condition 2")`.

Comment: Since this looks like a bug, please don't forget to file a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

As Tamás notes in the comments, this is likely a bug in the current implementation of SwiftUI. That said, I encountered this myself and used a `ZStack` with conditional `maxWidth` to achieve a similar effect. Your above code could be refactored to:

```
if player1Streak > 0 || player2Streak > 0 {
    HStack {
        Text("Winning streak:")
        ZStack {
            Text("\(player1Streak)").frame(maxWidth: player1Streak > 0 ? .infinity : 0.0)
            Text("\(player2Streak)").frame(maxWidth: player1Streak > 0 ? 0.0 : .infinity)
        }
        ZStack {
            Text("(\(player1Name))").frame(maxWidth: player1Streak > 0 ? .infinity : 0.0)
            Text("(\(player2Name))").frame(maxWidth: player1Streak > 0 ? 0.0 : .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't found an issue with this approach yet, and it should function as a workaround until the conditional `Text` bug is resolved. In the meantime, you should file a bug report at [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com)!